# dynamicaly parameterized FeignClients

Tags: feign, openfeign

I need to access different instances of a server sharing the same REST interface.

for one server, or different instances of the same server, I would use Ribbon and a feignClient, but the servers are not interchangeable.

I've got a list of server adresses in my application.yml file, likewise:

```
servers:
  - id: A
    url: http://url.a
  - id: B
    url: http://url.b
```

I'd like to be able to request a server regarding input parameter, for example:

```
ClientA -> /rest/api/request/A/get -> http://url.a/get
ClientB -> /rest/api/request/B/get -> http://url.b/get
```

The middleware is agnostic regarding the clients, but the backend server is bound to the clients.

```
many clients -> one middleware -> some clients
```

Who would you achieve that using Feign? is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to create two Feign targets using the reusing the interface and builder.

```java
Client clientA = Feign.builder()
                      .target(Client.class, "https://url.a");
Client clientB = Feign.builder()
                      .target(Client.class, "https://url.b");
```

This will create a new Client for each target url, however, by ensuring that the supporting components such as the `Encoder`, `Decoder`, `Client`, and `ErrorDecoder` are singleton instances and thread-safe, the cost of the client will be minimal.

If you don't want to create multiple clients, the alternative is to include a `URI` as a method parameter.

```java
@RequestLine("POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues")
void createIssue(URI host, Issue issue, @Param("owner") String owner, @Param("repo") String repo);
```

The value `host` in the example above will replace the base uri provided in the builder.  The drawback to this approach you will need to modify your interface to add this `URI` to the appropriate methods and adjust the callers to supply the target.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I ended up doing the first solution and map the clients in a configuration class